# Add a picture to UITabBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have view controllers added to my UITabBarController in the interface builder. How can I add a picture and change item title programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add them at 'applicationDidFinishLaunching:' function in appDelegate.m file.

for example :

```
NSInteger index = 0;
while(index < 4){ // 4 is the number of tabbar items
    UINavigationController *navCtrlr = (UINavigationController*)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index];
    UITabBarItem *tabBar = (UITabBarItem *) navCtrlr.tabBarItem;
    if(index == 0){
        tabBar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home-item.png"];
        tabBar.title = @"home";
    }
    ...
    index ++;
}
```